# Handling NULL values in SQL table when reading table in R

Tags: r, null, na, rodbc

I am reading a SQL table in R, using the following query:

[image]

```
data = sqlQuery(con, "select * from Quant.dbo.Indiv_data where Date > '19020101'", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, as.is = TRUE, na.string = "NULL", nullstring = "NA")
```

The use of `as.is` is not to cast any of the original column types, and to leave the column types of the SQL table as is. The only problem is that the "NULL" cells in the SQL table don't get handled properly, and I get the following result:

```
                      Date  issueid    ReturnBA          VAL           EQ          EFF        SIZE FSCR MSCR          SY
 1 1984-12-31 00:00:00.000 00101601  .136539672 45.200000000 71.400000000 47.750000000 1.295611077 <NA> <NA>  .019447467
 2 1984-12-31 00:00:00.000 00105401  .023985560 57.800000000 48.800000000 18.500000000 2.296439211 <NA> <NA> -.005433357
 3 1984-12-31 00:00:00.000 00109801 -.094036769 60.200000000 56.800000000 79.200000000 1.858392810 <NA> <NA> -.451707020
 4 1984-12-31 00:00:00.000 00112401 -.006317470 46.400000000 64.800000000 54.250000000 1.900126698 <NA> <NA>  .009264280
 5 1984-12-31 00:00:00.000 00116601  .124830071         <NA> 76.200000000 48.500000000 2.070191229 <NA> <NA>        <NA>
 6 1984-12-31 00:00:00.000 00117801  .010923909 25.500000000 29.000000000 40.666666667 2.200806054 <NA> <NA> -.005433421
```

Note that the "NULL" cells get transformed as `<NA>`, instead of `NA`. To try to handle this case, I tried the following:

```
 data = sqlQuery(con, "select * from Quant.dbo.Indiv_data where Date > '19020101'",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, as.is = TRUE, na.string = "NULL", nullstring = "NA")
```

This, however, sets every NULL cell to the **string NA** rather than the **symbol** `NA`.
In other words, if you take the example of `data$VAL[5]`, which was initially NULL in the SQL table, and do the following:

`is.na(data$VAL[5])` you get `FALSE` but when doing
`data$VAL[5] == "NA"` you get `TRUE`

How can I make all the `NULL` cells in SQL table be `NA` in the dataframe in R, while using `as.is` in `sqlQuery()`?

Thank you,

Comment: Your screenshot seems to imply that the "NULL" values in your data base are not actually `NULL`, but rather the strings "NULL". Is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean by **string NA**? do you mean `NA_character_`?

Comment: By string NA, I mean "NA", and not the symbol NA

Comment: @Joran I believe is is actually the symbol `NULL`, not the string.

Comment: So, there is no (real) difference between `NA` and `<NA>`. The latter is simply how R prints the NA value in the case of a character variable, in order to distinguish from other strings. The fact that R did this, and that `na.string = "NULL"` caused this behavior, strongly suggests that the NULL values in your db are actually strings. So the "numeric" columns with this "NULL" values are being imported as character variables.

Comment: It is very odd, as the column VAL for example is a numeric(18,9) type, but gets imported in R as a character column. How come that happens, even when I specified `as.is`?

Comment: Maybe. I would consider the use of the string "NULL" to represent missing data in a database column to be a much bigger problem.

Comment: You just made me realize that the actual problem is that all my "numeric" columns in SQL have been imported as character columns. How can I resolve that?

Comment: The only explanation that makes any sense is that you are in fact mistaken about the structure of your db. If the columns were numeric, R would import them as such.

Comment: Well, I am looking as we speak at my SQL table, and I am explicitly seeing that my first two columns are Datetime and varchar(255), while all the other columns are `numeric(18,9)`. I believe I may not be using `as.is` properly.. do you think it's that?

Comment: No, I think you're wrong about what's in your db. We've already established that the NULL values are actually strings in your db.

Comment: ...unless we're wrong about what's in your db. Screenshots are not very informative, so it's hard to say. What happens if you just omit the `as.is` argument and let R choose a type for each column?

Comment: If I don't use `as.is`, then numeric columns stay numeric. I am not wrong about what's in my table, and I finally found a solution: only specify `as.is` for the columns you wish would become `character` or `Date`, and `FALSE` for the rest. If I exclude `as.is` completely, every column would be fine except for the second column: that column is a character column but R would cast it as numeric.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that it seems that `as.is` converts all columns (except the Date column) to `character` columns. Therefore, R prints `<NA>` as null symbol for character vectors/columns.

The solution is to specify `as.is` only for the first two columns, and let R take care of the other column types. In this case, R would appropriately cast the rest of the columns as numeric, and assign `NA` as null symbol for equivalent empty cells in SQL.